# php pagination for my members

Tags: php, pagination

You guys are helping me greatly. Please I have created a members page which I want to use pagination but it shows only one member's id in all ids.

Here is an image:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MEMBERS</title>
<link rel="icon" href="guyt.gif" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<div id="sidebar">
<br>

<?php include 'lists.php'; ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the lists.php code which contains the pagination:

```
<?php
$per_page = 5;

if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = 1;
} else {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

if($page<=1)
$start = 0;
else
    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;

    $mem_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM register");
    while($run_mem = mysql_fetch_array($mem_query)){
        $id = $run_mem['id'];
        $first = getuser($id, 'first');
        $last = getuser($id, 'last');
    }


$sql = "SELECT * FROM register";

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));

$num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page);



$sql .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
While($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div class='header'><table width='98%'><tr><td><div align='left'>$first $last</div></td><td><div align='right'><a href='profile.php?user=$id'>VISIT PROFILE</a></div></td></tr></table></div><br>";
    }

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;

echo "<hr>";

if($prev > 0)
echo "<a href='?page=$prev' class='box'>Previous</a></font> ";

if($page < ceil($num_rows/$per_page))
echo " <a href='?page=$next' class='box'>Next</a></font>";


?>
```

if I change this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM register";
```

to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='$id'";
```

it will display like that same user but just once. please help me

Comment: you should stop using mysql commands. it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should output the property of each row you are looping in :

```
While($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<div class='header'><table width='98%'><tr><td><div align='left'>" . $row['name'] . "</div></td><td><div align='right'><a href='profile.php?user=$id'>VISIT PROFILE</a></div></td></tr></table></div><br>";
}
```

That's assuming the name is stored in a "name" key. Adapt it to your db structure.